# How to pre-select cells in Shiny DT datatables

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there a way to pre-select cells in shiny DT datatables instead of rows?

```
library(shiny)
if (packageVersion('DT') < '0.1.3') devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h1('Client-side processing'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1')

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = c(1, 3, 8, 12),target="cell")
    )

  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the github guide which has exactly what you are looking for (in this question and others you have posted recently). https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

> 2.1.4 Pre-selection
>
> The selection argument of datatable() can also include a component
>   selected to specify which rows/columns/cells to be
>   pre-selected when the table is initialized. When target = 'row' or
>   'column', selected is a vector of row or column indices. For the case
>   of target = 'row+column', selected should be a list of two components
>   rows and cols, e.g. list(rows = c(1, 2, 4, 9), cols = c(1, 3)). For
>   target = 'cell', it should be a matrix of two columns: the first
>   column is the row indices of selected cells, and the second column is
>   the column indices.

In order for it to select a certain cell, you have to give it coordinates (row and column).

```
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h1('Client-side processing'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1')

    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 4), nrow = 2, ncol = 3),target="cell")
    )

  }
)
```

Comment: how do I pre-select only the first cell? I have a data frame with one column and multiple rows and the first cell of this df (which is the first row in this case) needs to be selected. Thank you!

Comment: @MaMo please create a new question, with a reproducible example of your problem and post the link here. Happy to help.

Comment: I posted my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906457/pre-select-cell-in-shiny-app-datatable-with-one-column