# Pre-select cell in Shiny app datatable with one column

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have an data table output in my Shiny app and want to pre-select the first cell of it. I created a very simple example below with one column and the target cell as selection option.

```
library(DT)
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h1('Data table'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab')

    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
     col1 = c('Car', 'Truck', 'Bike') 
     df = data.frame(col1)

     output$tab = DT::renderDataTable(
        df, server = FALSE,
        selection = list(mode = 'single',target="cell"), 
        rownames= FALSE
    )
  }
)
```

How can I (in this case) pre-select the first cell (Car)?

I found this: [How to pre-select cells in Shiny DT datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627988/how-to-pre-select-cells-in-shiny-dt-datatables/58629137#comment103949883_58629137)

In this post I read that I have to use a matrix as selection criteria, but I am not able to get it right i my example.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve this problem since your DT only contains 1 column.

1. You can have `target = 'row'` (works since you only have 1 column, so each row is only 1 cell).

Solution:

```
library(DT)
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h1('Data table'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab')

    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    col1 = c('Car', 'Truck', 'Bike') 
    df = data.frame(col1)

    output$tab = DT::renderDataTable(
      df, server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'single',target="row", selected = 1), 
      rownames= FALSE
    )
  }
)
```

2. You can have `target = 'cell'`. In this case you have to create a matrix of the first cell and the trick here is knowing the column index starts at 0 in DT.

> For target = 'cell', it should be a matrix of two columns: the first
>   column is the row indices of selected cells, and the second column is
>   the column indices. -- From [DT Github](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html)

Solution:

```
library(DT)
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h1('Data table'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab')

    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    col1 = c('Car', 'Truck', 'Bike') 
    df = data.frame(col1)

    output$tab = DT::renderDataTable(
      df, server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'single',target="cell", selected = matrix(c(1, 0), nrow = 1, ncol = 2)), 
      rownames= FALSE
    )
  }
)
```

*Update*

From OP's comments, `input$tab_cell_clicked` is blank since pre-select does not generate a `click` action.

To get this effect, simply add an `if statement` for this affect.

```
click = ifelse(input$tab_cell_clicked == "", col1[1], input$tab_cell_clicked)
```

**This is untested but the idea is there.

Comment: this highlights the cell, but it does not have the same effect as clicking on it right? because my input$tab_cell_clicked does not have a value this way. can I pass it to the variable?

Comment: Correct, it won't have the same effect. I'll update the answer for that.

Comment: thank you! I tried accessing the value of the table at input$tab_cells_selected[1,1] inside an observe() and pass it to input$tab_cell$clicked$value but it did not work.

Comment: Please select the answer as correct if it helped you solve your issue, this helps other people know it was correct.