# Single column selection in DT datatable R

Tags: r, datatable, dt

I know we can enable column selection instead of row selection for a DT::datatable like so:

```
DT::datatable(
  myTable, 
  selection = list(target = "column"))
```

And for row selection tables, we can enable single-select like so:

```
DT::datatable(
  myTable, 
  selection = "single")
```

However is there a way to combine the two and have a single-column selection? I've tried things like

```
selection = list(target = "column", select = "single")
```

or

```
selection = list(target = "column", selection = "single")
```

However nothing seems to work and I can't find anything in the doc either.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the list argument "mode" as follows:

```
DT::datatable(
    myTable, 
    selection = list(mode = "single",
                     target = "column"))
```

I just ran into this myself and solved it reviewing the question by [@MaMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9283258/mamo) on this [other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906457/pre-select-cell-in-shiny-app-datatable-with-one-column). Cheers and hope this helps.